# How to use columns to create queries (e.g. WHERE clause)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with a column with one row with *where clause*.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
where_clause_df=spark.createDataFrame([('A > 1',)],schema=StructType([StructField("a_where", StringType(), nullable=True)]))
where_clause_df.createOrReplaceTempView("where_clause").show()

spark.sql("select * from where_clause").show()
+-------+
|a_where|
+-------+
|  A > 1|
+-------+
```

With another table,

```
sample_df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,)],schema=StructType([StructField("A", IntegerType(), nullable=True)]))
sample_df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample")
spark.sql("select * from sample").show()
```

I want to use this `a_where` to apply with the table `sample`. Something like:

```
spark.sql("""
select * from sample where (select a_where from where_clause)
""").show()
```

Is it possible with Spark SQL ?

Comment: I think there are a couple of questions that need to be answered first. How do you match records between the two dataframes? In other words, how do you know which condition to apply to which rows from `sample_df`? Or you must just apply all the conditions of `where_clause_df`? Then again, why do you store these conditions in a dataframe? You will have million of them :)? If not maybe you should just consider a single array/list etc

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Use `collect` on the `where_clause` table.

---

Think of data as something available (almost) always on executors where you are not allowed to execute queries from. That's by design.

Since you want to execute queries you should have all you need on the driver and so you need to bring this extra metadata for your queries (like `where` clauses) to the driver. Bingo! That's exactly `collect`.

Mind though that the data you can "download" to the driver using `collect` has to be within the amount of memory available for this one single driver process (and that's likely the case).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract the where clause string from your TempView, hence getting the error

You can modify your code slightly to achieve this

```
where_clause_df=sql.createDataFrame([('A > 1',)],schema=StructType([StructField("a_where", StringType(), nullable=True)]))

where_clause_df.createOrReplaceTempView("where_clause")

sql.sql("select * from where_clause").show()


sample_df=sql.createDataFrame([(1,)],schema=StructType([StructField("A", IntegerType(), nullable=True)]))
sample_df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample")

sql.sql("select * from sample").show()

### Contains 'A > 1'
where_clause = sql.sql("select a_where from where_clause").collect()[0][0]

query = f"""
    select * 
    from sample 
    where {where_clause}
"""

sql.sql(query).show()

+---+
|  A|
+---+
+---+
```

Further if there are multiple conditions , you can iterate over them and modify the query in each iteration to extract the results

Comment: Thank you but it is that I do not wish. I want to apply one action, not two. It's the chalenge ;-)